# Why is my div being pushing down when p tags are added to the bottom of a sibling div?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs sitting side-by-side inside a form element. Normally, they both line up against the top of the form.

However, when I add p tags(class forget) to the bottom of the second sibling div, the first div is pushed down from the top of the form. The second div stays up against the top of the form element.

I don't understand why the p tags at the bottom of the second sibling div are adding margin/padding to the top of the first div.

One clue is that setting `vertical-align: top` fixes the problem, but I want to know what is causing it.

```css
form {
  color: white;
  width: 430px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.formEmail,
.formPassword {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 165px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form id="logIn">
  <div class="formEmail">
    <p>Email or Phone</p>
    <input type="text" name="emailphone">
  </div>
  <div class="formPassword">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <p class="forget">Forget Account?</p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align: top` to the two divs: https://jsfiddle.net/pobbLs21/ They're set to either baseline or middle I guess in your reset (if you're using one).

Comment: I would change and say that `baseline` is the default, hence the left alignment becomes odd in this case ... still, +1

Comment: @LGSon Yes baseline is default, but also depends on if a reset is used or not. I have seen some resets using vertical-align: middle

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow:hidden;` to the divs

```css
form {
  color: white;
  width: 430px;
  height: 80px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.formEmail,
.formPassword {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 165px;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form id="logIn">
  <div class="formEmail">
    <p>Email or Phone</p>
    <input type="text" name="emailphone">
  </div>
  <div class="formPassword">
    <p>Password</p>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <p class="forget">Forget Account?</p>
  </div>
</form>
```